# How to pass a selected value to a html popup window

Tags: php, html

This might be a popular question but I couldn't find the answer I'm looking for.
Anyway What I want to do is pass an option value in the parent window to a popup window so I can display some thing in the popup according to the selected option.here is my code of the parent window.

```
<select name="itemSelect" id="itemSelect">
<option>chair</option>
<option>table</option>
</select>
<a class="button" href="#" onclick= "MyWindow=window.open('form3.php','MyWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=500,height=650'); return false;">enter data</a>
```

Comment: what about query string like form3.php?Id=3

Comment: Append the selected value as a query string to the URL you're opening in the pop-up window.

Comment: try to get value on onchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a class="button" href="#" onclick= "MyWindow=window.open('form3.php?itemSelect='+document.getElementById('itemSelect').value,'MyWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=500,height=650'); return false;">enter data</a>
```

Then in form3.php

```
echo $itemSelect = $_GET['itemSelect'];
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to get this itemSelect value to the popup

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery, you could do something this.

```
value = $('#itemSelect option:selected').val();
window.open('form3.php?value='+value+', MyWindow
```

You could then look for `$_GET['value']` on the PHP page and process it!

Comment: No need to include jQuery just for this.

Comment: @mishik i didnt, and therefore i just upvoted you to counter your unnessecary downvote ;)

Comment: Ok, noted. I still stand by my point of not including jQuery, but silently :)

Comment: @mishik thats ok by me, it wasnt supposed to be the focus of the answer, just the quickest option if jquery was already included! Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via special `onclick` handler by adding your value via hash or url param:

```
<a class="button" href="#" onclick= "openNewWindow()">enter data</a>
```

JS:

```
function openNewWindow() {
  var your_select = document.getElementById("itemSelect");
  var value = your_select.options[your_select.selectedIndex].value;
  MyWindow=window.open('form3.php#' + value,
      'MyWindow',
      'toolbar=no,location=no,...,width=500,height=650');
  // ... or
  // MyWindow = window.open('form3.php?select_value=' + value, ...

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But can you tell be how to php echo the variable "your_select" of javascript

Comment: For PHP - use the second option (with `?select_value=`) and you should be able to see it in `$_GET['select_value']`

Comment: I'm sorry. I Cant understand. I know very little about javascript. Can you please explain this a little bit..

Comment: That's more for PHP rather than javascript. Do you have the code for `form3.php`? If you open new window via `MyWindow = window.open('form3.php?select_value=abc',...)` you will then be able to use value of `select_value` in `form3.php` script via `$_GET['select_value']`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass the selected option to a pop up window for better interaction?

It would be easier to use `alert()` in js; using `onclick` handler you can call a function in js which then displays the pop up by using `alert(document.getElementById().value=variable)`